# Android Content Resolver takePersistableUriPermission API below 19 no such method

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I`m using this in order to achieve the following behavior:

User selects files via `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` for API above 19 (The new Storage Access Framework) or via `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` for API below 19. The files should be stored in the app`s list for later use (open them). So after I get the files I use:

```
Uri uri = fileUri;
final int takeFlags = data.getFlags()
          & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
          | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
```

For the cases of API above 19 it works fine, but for API below 19, for example I test with API 14, I got ANR with following error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.ContentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission`

What can be the problem? Thanks,

UPDATE: It seems it`s (Persistent Permission) done automatically in API below 14, which means just comment out this code if API is below 14.

Comment: public void takePersistableUriPermission (Uri uri, int modeFlags)

Added in API level 19

Comment: Yes, but how to achieve the UX I need: The user can open the files in later use... (Persistent Permission)

Comment: Alright - it seems it`s done automatically in API below 14...